# Custom back button added as overlay to AVPlayercontroller not clickable in tvos

Tags: swift, swiftui, avplayer, tvos, avplayerviewcontroller

In  swiftui tv os application avplayercontroller is used to play video. I have added back button as overlay in AVPlayercontroller. Custom back button is not clickable in tvos. The action event does not trigger

```swift
struct PlayVideo: View {
    
    @AppStorage("selectedVideo")  var videoName : String  = "video1. mp4"

    @State var player = AVPlayer(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "video4",
                                                      withExtension: "mp4")!)
    @State var isPlaying: Bool = false
    
    
    let toPresent = UIHostingController(rootView: AnyView(EmptyView()))
    @State  var path  = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "video1", ofType:"mp4")
    
   
    
    var body: some View {
    //  AVPlayerView(videoURL: self.$vURL).transition(.move(edge: .bottom)).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
       // VStack  {
         //   Text("Video player")
            AVPlayerView(videoURL: self.$path)
                .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .overlay(
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 24)
                    {
                        Button(action: {
                            print("back clicked")
                           // self.buttonClicked()
                        }, label: {
                            
                            HStack  {
                               /* Image("Next")
                                    .frame(width: 15.5, height: 13)
                 
                                Spacer()
                                        .frame(width: 20)*/

                                Text("Back")
                                    .font(.interDisplay(.semiBold, size: 20))
                                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                                    .frame(width: 110, height: 44, alignment: .leading)


                            }
                            
                            
                        })
                        .buttonStyle(.automatic)

                        


                })
              //  .frame(width: UIScreen.screenWidth, height: UIScreen.screenHeight-200)
        //}
        .onAppear {
            print("on apper value",videoName)
            var videoArray = videoName.components(separatedBy: ".")
            
            var fileName = ""
            if videoArray.count > 0  {
                fileName = videoArray[0]
            }
            
            var fileType = ""
            if videoArray.count > 1  {
                fileType = videoArray[1]
            }

            path  = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType:fileType)
            
            print("new path is",path)
            
        }

    }

}
struct AVPlayerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    @Binding var videoURL: String?
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    private var player: AVPlayer {
        return AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: videoURL!))
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ playerController: AVPlayerViewController, context: Context) {
        playerController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        playerController.player = player
        playerController.player?.play()

        // Add custom overlay with a back button using SwiftUI Button
        let backButton = Button(action: {
            print("back action")
            context.coordinator.backButtonTapped()
        }) {
            Text("Back")
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.blue) // Customize button appearance as needed
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .cornerRadius(8)
        .buttonStyle(.card)


        // Add the SwiftUI button as a hosting controller
        let buttonController = UIHostingController(rootView: backButton)
        playerController.addChild(buttonController)
        playerController.contentOverlayView?.addSubview(buttonController.view)

        // Ensure the button is focusable
        buttonController.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        buttonController.view.isAccessibilityElement = true

        buttonController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            buttonController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: playerController.contentOverlayView!.topAnchor, constant: 20),
            buttonController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: playerController.contentOverlayView!.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
        ])
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        let viewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        viewController.delegate = context.coordinator
        return viewController
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate {
        var parent: AVPlayerView

        init(_ parent: AVPlayerView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func backButtonTapped() {
            print("back clicked")
            parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

1. I have added back button in Playvideoview but click event not triggered
2. I have added back button in AVPlayerView view but click event not triggerd

How to resolve the issue

I have also tried to add button using zstack but click event not triggered.

```swift
struct PlayVideo: View {
    
    @AppStorage("selectedVideo")  var videoName : String  = "video1. mp4"

    @State var player = AVPlayer(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "video1",
                                                      withExtension: "mp4")!)
    @State var isPlaying: Bool = false
    
   /* var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VideoPlayer(player: player)
                .frame(width: UIScreen.screenWidth, height: UIScreen.screenHeight-200, alignment: .top)


            Button {
                isPlaying ? player.pause() : player.play()
                isPlaying.toggle()
                player.seek(to: .zero)
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: isPlaying ? "stop" : "play")
                    .padding()
            }
        }
    }*/
    
    let toPresent = UIHostingController(rootView: AnyView(EmptyView()))
    @State  var path  = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "video1", ofType:"mp4")
   // @State private var vURL = URL(string: "https://www.radiantmediaplayer.com/media/bbb-360p.mp4")
    
   
    
    var body: some View {
    //  AVPlayerView(videoURL: self.$vURL).transition(.move(edge: .bottom)).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
       // VStack  {
         //   Text("Video player")
        ZStack {
            AVPlayerView(videoURL: self.$path)
                .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 24)
            {
                Button(action: {
                    print("back clicked")
                   // self.buttonClicked()
                }, label: {
                    
                    HStack  {
                       /* Image("Next")
                            .frame(width: 15.5, height: 13)
         
                        Spacer()
                                .frame(width: 20)*/

                        Text("Back")
                            .font(.interDisplay(.semiBold, size: 20))
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .frame(width: 110, height: 44, alignment: .leading)


                    }

                    
                    
                })
                .buttonStyle(.card)
                .zIndex(1)

        }
        }
               /* .overlay(
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 24)
                    {
                        Button(action: {
                            print("back clicked")
                           // self.buttonClicked()
                        }, label: {
                            
                            HStack  {
                               /* Image("Next")
                                    .frame(width: 15.5, height: 13)
                 
                                Spacer()
                                        .frame(width: 20)*/

                                Text("Back")
                                    .font(.interDisplay(.semiBold, size: 20))
                                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                                    .frame(width: 110, height: 44, alignment: .leading)


                            }

                            
                            
                        })
                        .buttonStyle(.automatic)
                        .zIndex(1)


                       
                        


                })*/
              //  .frame(width: UIScreen.screenWidth, height: UIScreen.screenHeight-200)
        //}
        .onAppear {
            print("on apper value",videoName)
            var videoArray = videoName.components(separatedBy: ".")
            
            var fileName = ""
            if videoArray.count > 0  {
                fileName = videoArray[0]
            }
            
            var fileType = ""
            if videoArray.count > 1  {
                fileType = videoArray[1]
            }

            path  = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType:fileType)
            
            print("new path is",path)
            
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you also tried with `ZStack` and `zIndex`?

Comment: @TaeeunKim Yes i have tried using zstack but click event not working. see updated question